# I have a terrible problem with downloading apps and upgrading my 32bit Zorin OS 15 lite, can someone please help me?

Tags: dpkg, zorin

I am trying to install a new app doing upgrading my 32bit zorin os 15 lite system. I keep getting these messages in the terminal:

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), is another process using it?
```

I need help please. How can I overcome this terrible messages

Comment: Sounds like you're not running something as root or with `sudo`. Not familiar enough with what you're talking about to make this an answer, and don't run `sudo` on something you don't trust.

Comment: Impossible to tell, unless you show us what you did. What command did you type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously your lock (`/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`) indicates that either another process (maybe the update process) is just using dpkg and tells you that you cannot use it. If the problem persists you need to find out which process is holding it.

Find that out:

`lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend`

That process is responsible for not releasing the lock file. Either kill it or update your question by [editing your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/594072/edit) and place the result of the command above.

Comment: I try to install TLP through the terminal , but I get this message "Media change: please insert the disc labeled
 'Zorin-OS 15.2 Lite 32bit'
in the drive '/media/cdrom/' and press [Enter] "   can someone please help me out ? I am so new to linux zorin os.

Comment: Ask a new question, describe what you have done, paste the error messages. Do not ask 2 questions in one thread